# TCP able to send only first message

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I make client-sever app. It look like this:

client

```
import socket
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1338
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    st = input("Your message: ")
    byt = st.encode()
    s.send(byt)
```

server

```
import socket
host = ''
port = 1338
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
while True:
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = conn.recv(2000)
    print(data.decode())
```

Problem is that only first message is display. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server receives data only once after accepting a connection from the client. In-order to receive continuously, you can have a while loop for receiving data from the client.

```
import socket
host = ''
port = 1338
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
while True:
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    condition = True
    while condition:
        data = conn.recv(2000)
        if not data: break
        print(data.decode())
```

So, the above code will receive data as long the user provides data. You can separate the data receiving part in a separate thread too.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the client's `connect` outside the loop, you have to place the server's `listen` and `accept` also outside the loop, since the connection is to be established only once.